# Angular material fullscreen layout broken by Google Sign-In button

Tags: angular-material, google-signin

I'm trying to use the Google Sign-In button in a fullscreen Angular Material layout (based on https://github.com/angular/material-start), but as soon as it renders, the page layout grows just slightly taller than full screen. For example you can scroll down just a little bit past the supposedly full-height side navigation and see its drop shadow.

What is the button doing to my layout, and how do I fix fullscreen layout while using the button?

Comment: it looks like signin uses a hidden iframe to communicate with the IdP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be fixed by adding a style to the embedding page, to `display: none` the iframe, which is otherwise a 1-pixel affair shoved offscreen to the side. In my testing it still does its job when completely hidden.